# How to get attribute table information when clicking on OpenLayers webgis?

Tags: python, javascript, openlayers, sql

Might seems like a very trivial question to ask, but I am currently facing the problem with webGIS using JavaScript and python (with flask and psycopg2) where I load some shapefiles into pgadmin with PostGIS installed. I can see the vector layers, but I cannot think of solution how I can get information from attribute table.

Comment: Have you tried using a WMS (GetFeatureInfo operation) or WFS (GetFeature or DescribeFeatureType operations)?

Comment: Thank for comment :) I have not tried. But can I use these operations even when I am not using those services (WMS, WFS), I had some shapefiles and I used Postgis shapefile loader to make spatial databases from them. I visualised them with ST_json_build_object into webgis on server. Do you think I can use the way you suggested even with it?